# Streaming desktop to webcam with avconv

Tags: avconv

I'm trying to use avconv to capture my desktop and stream it on my webcam. Unfortunately I do not know what output format I should use to do this. The following is what I currently have.

```
avconv -f x11grab -s 1920x1080 -r 30 -i :0.0+0,0
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the `man` pages [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/avconv.1.html), it shows that you can list the available codecs with `avconv -codecs`. It's basically personal preference of what codec you want to use for the output. It seems that AVI is the default.